# How to restore a SQLite database from a .db file in the external storage of an android device?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, backup, restore

I have the following code to make the backup, how can I implement the restore of that backup when the user selects the backup file from their android´s file system?

code I have to backup:

```
   try {

                final String inFileName = "/data/data/{my package name}/databases/data";
                File dbFile = new File(inFileName);
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dbFile);

                String outFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/database_copy.db";

                // Open the empty db as the output stream
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

                // Transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = fis.read(buffer))>0){
                    output.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }

                // Close the streams
                output.flush();
                output.close();
                fis.close();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Backup was successfully made", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "An error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Comment: Just copy the file in the other direction. (Ensure that the DB is no open.)